# POS Application - Simplify SQL Mutli-Queries(MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

Hei guy I'm working on a POS app with MySQL. Here is my situation:

Table "purchased_item"

```
|    id    |    name    |    check_id    |    real_price    |
|    1     |   iPhone5  |      0001      |       399        |
|    2     |   iPhone4  |      0001      |       199        |
|    3     |   iPhone5s |      0002      |       599        |
|    4     |   iPhone5c |      0003      |       399        |
|    5     |   iMac 21" |      0003      |       999        |
|    6     | iPod Touch |      0003      |        99        |
|    7     |   iPhone5  |      0004      |       399        |
|    8     |   iPhone3G |      0004      |        99        |
|    9     |   iPhone6  |      0005      |       899        |
|    10    |  iPhone3Gs |      0005      |       101        |
```

And I want to know how many checks's total are larger than or qual(>=) 1000, so what I'm doing now is to do several times of query. In this example, I do 5 times and sum it manually by the host program.

Later the data grow, the queries become slow because there're tons of checks everyday. So I change to record it to another table.

Table "checks"

```
|    id    |    total    |    sales    |
|   0001   |     598     |      A      |
|   0002   |     599     |      A      |
|   0003   |     1497    |      B      |
|   0004   |     498     |      B      |
|   0005   |     1000    |      A      |
```

But another problem occur in the later time: When I need to adjust the real_price in "purchased_item" table, I also need to maintain the "total" column in "checks" table. It sounds doesn't a big matter but I'd like to find a better way to solve it.

Solved:

```
SELECT * FROM purchased_item
GROUP BY check_id
HAVING sum(real_price) >= 1000
```

And the result will be:

```
|    id    |    name    |    check_id    |    real_price    |
|    4     |   iPhone5c |      0003      |       399        |
|    9     |   iPhone6  |      0005      |       899        |
```

Further question: If I want to count the total price for checks, how can I do it?
I found it:

```
SELECT check_id,sum(real_price) FROM purchased_item
GROUP BY check_id
HAVING sum(real_price) >= 1000
```

Comment: But check_id 0003 is applied for iphone5c, imac 21 and ipod touch. And check_id 0005 applies for iphone6 and iphone3gs. (0003 and 0005 are above 1000 in total)

Comment: If you need toy show `check_id` with sum of `real_price` more then 100, why you are showing only `iPhone5c` not `iPhone3Gs` as it is part of `check_id` 0005?

Comment: bcoz i want to remove duplicated record, or I should say, I want to count how many checks's total are over 1000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way

```
SELECT i.id, i.name, i.check_id, i.real_price
  FROM 
(
  SELECT MIN(id) id
    FROM purchased_item 
   GROUP BY check_id
  HAVING SUM(real_price) >= 1000
) q JOIN purchased_item i
    ON q.id = i.id
 ORDER BY q.id DESC
```

Sample output:

```
| ID |     NAME | CHECK_ID | REAL_PRICE |
|----|----------|----------|------------|
|  9 |  iPhone6 |        5 |        899 |
|  4 | iPhone5c |        3 |        399 |
```

---

> *...I want to count how many checks's total are over 1000*

For that you can just do this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) total
  FROM
(
  SELECT check_id
    FROM purchased_item 
   GROUP BY check_id
  HAVING SUM(real_price) >= 1000
) q;
```

Sample output:

```
| TOTAL |
|-------|
|     2 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/82e55/10)** demo

---

To update `total` in `checks` after adjusting `real_price` in `purchased_item`

```
UPDATE checks c JOIN 
(
  SELECT check_id, SUM(real_price) total
    FROM purchased_item 
   WHERE check_id IN(5) -- whatever check(s)'s total you want to recalculate
   GROUP BY check_id
) p
    ON c.id = p.check_id
   SET c.total = p.total;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/21ac30/2)** demo

Comment: GROUP BY is simplest solution. Thanks!